# Does cron run scheduled but missed script(because of sleeping) after wake up?

Tags: shell-script, fedora, cron

I use fedora20 and its default cron. I have a cron job script that puts the server to sleep at 10:30am with rtcwake, and it wakes up at 12:30pm. If I run the script manually at 9:40am, it will also wake up at 12:30pm. If I run the script manually at 9:40am, will it run the missed cron task at 10:30am after wake up at 12:30pm and goes to sleep right away(which makes it wake up at 3:30pm)?

That seems to be what is happening with my server, and I want to know if the cron runs the missed job after wakeup.  If so, is there any way to change this behavior?  Thank you very  much.

Answer (score 3):

Fedora defaults to [chronie](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie), which incorporates anacron-like functionality to run jobs periodically even when the system is off. The defaut `/etc/anacrontab` looks like this:

```
#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

... which means that by default any scripts you put into one of those directories (`/etc/cron.[daily,weekly,monthly]`) will run even if the computer is off. However, stuff in `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d` or user crontabs won't work that way. Look at `man anacrontab` for how to add new entries, if the existing periodic schedules don't work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I just found out it uses anacron. And my script is in the root crontab. But there is another entry at 1:30pm in root cron to put it to sleep till 3:30pm.  But that 1:30pm missed cronjob does not get executed at 3:30pm when it wakes up. So, if I manually put the server to sleep at 9:40, the skipped job at 10:30 gets run when it wakes up at 12:30, and goes to sleep at 12:31, but 1:30 skpped job does not run at 3:30pm when it is up.  Is there any rules regarding this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Not all `cron` daemons handle cases for noncontinuous uptime.  One which is specifically designed to run "missed" jobs is [`anacron`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  How do I find if fedora cron runs missed job or not?  If I run the script manually 9:40am, it wakes up at 12:30pm and goes to sleep right away at 12:31pm. And the only reason for this seems to be the missed cron job at 10:30am.  Thank you..

Comment: Fedora (probably) has a selection/choice of crons. Use the package manager to find out which one(s) is/are installed.